# VBS Excel to PDF

Tags: excel, pdf, vbscript

I have got an excel sheet that is used to make invoices. Now, I want to export this as PDF and send it on outlook. I managed to create a code that works. The only part which I am not sure about is that there are some parts of the excel sheet that I don't want to be saved into the PDF. I was wondering if anyone knows a way to do that? I guess it would have to do with changing the part of the code which I am attaching, but I'm not sure what.

Thanks

```
Create the PDF
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, 
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the code right there. I assume you have a particular range you would want to export? If so then change code:

```
ActiveSheet.range("A1:B10").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating
```

For multiple ranges to a singel pdf:

```
ActiveSheet.range("A1:B10, A20:B30, A40:B60").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating
```

For multiple ranges to a single pdf without breaks in the pdf:

```
Sheets("Sheets2").UsedRange.ClearContents
Set myRange = Application.Union(Range("A1:B10"), Range("A20:B30"))
myRange.Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, =OpenPDFAfterCreating
```

Change the range(s) accordingly

Comment: Right, but the parts that I want to remove are in the middle of the worksheet so is there any way of skipping them? do I just create multiple ranges?

Comment: Yes you can, i altered the code above to (if correct) will do just that.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried that, the problem is that for each range there is a new pdf page saved, as opposed to being together. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this, if it works i'll add it to the above code. Cant check right now if it actually works. Set myRange = Application.Union(Range("A1:B10"), Range("A20:B30")). Then of course use myRange.Exportas.....

Comment: no, doesn't seem to be making a difference. Just to be sure when I DIM it, I store it as Range, right?

Comment: I got to try it myself now and you right. So I updated the code above which (over here atleast) leaves me with one PDF with no breaks.

Comment: What is the sheets2? if i replace it with the sheet im working with it deletes it and saves the pdf as empty (just my table, all the text is gone)

Comment: I assume you are extracting the range you want to export to pdf from your first sheet -> Sheet1 (or change name accordingly). What the code does now is Union the different ranges to one range and paste it to your second sheet, in my case named Sheet2. Just alter the code to your specific sheet names and it should work just fine.